# table, td, div heigth 100% doesn't work

Tags: css, height

I have a problem with my layout. I want 3 columns: the first and the last smaller than the central one.

This is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CL333/

I have this HTML

```
 <body>
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="sinistra">
                <div id="divsinistra">sinistra</div>
            <td id="centro"><div id="divcentro">centro</div>
            <td id="destra"><div id="divdestra">destra</div>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

and this CSS

```
 html{
height: 100%;
 }
body{
height: 100%;
 }

 #container{
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
 }
 #sinistra{
min-height: 100%;
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid red;
 }
 #centro{
min-height: 100%;
border: 1px solid red;
 }
 #destra{
min-height: 100%;
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid red;
 }
 table, table tr{
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
 }
 #divsinistra,#divcentro,#divdestra{
min-height: 100%;
 }
```

the problem is that I would like these columns fit the entire height of the page while in this way they are very small. I don't know where else put another height 100% :( Someone can hel me?
Thanks!

Comment: 1st of all, please note that body tag does not refer to `#body` css reference. same goes with `#html`

Comment: @HeHui thanks, what a stupid :-( but this is not the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you referenced your tags wrongly

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

and table does not work with min-height.

```
#container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

**[check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/CL333/1/)**

**EDIT**
I also forgot to mention that your html tags weren't closed properly.

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td id="sinistra">
                    <div id="divsinistra">sinistra</div>
                </td>
                <td id="centro"><div id="divcentro">centro</div></td>
                <td id="destra"><div id="divdestra">destra</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: also, for future reference, do check out my question on how table widths and heights work in html. the heirachy of "importance" really

Comment: and now, if I would like to insert another table in the middle coloumn how can I manage the heigth? I do you an example

Comment: I'm assuming you want the height to be a fixed height? just set the inner table height to a certain pixel

Comment: but I don't want this, I want that the table fits the page.